# Extend an element behind a scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, transparent

How can I make colored banners inside a container extend underneath a transparent scrollbar?

I want to use a custom scrollbar that's partially transparent which let's you see whatever background is behind it. Within the scrollable content there are banners which are differing colors. The example code below shows these banners extending as far as the scrollbar, then stopping, leaving the transparent scrollbar to show the background color of the container, which makes the whole transparent effect of the scrollbar kind of ugly. How can I extend these banners underneath the scrollbar?

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: black;
}

#banner1, #banner2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

#banner1 {background: red}
#banner2 {background: yellow}


/* Creates a transparent scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 16px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='banner1'></div>
  <div id='banner2'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found a solution.

If it's the body tag that's scrolling, than the width of each background strip can be set to 100vw (the width of the window including the scrollbars), then overflow-x: hidden can be set on the body tag to remove the horizontal scrollbar.

This solution only seems to work if it's the body that's doing the scrolling. Any other div with overflow-x: hidden makes anything going under the scrollbars disappear, this doesn't happen with the body tag for whatever reason.

Sample html file:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <style>
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #banner1, #banner2 {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 75%;
    }

    #banner1 {background: red}
    #banner2 {background: yellow}

    /* Creates a transparent scrollbar */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 16px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      border: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
      background-clip: padding-box;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    }
    </style>
    <div id='banner1'></div>
    <div id='banner2'></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

[View this screenshot of the page working correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljT7p.png)